# Pentaho User Console(PUC) parameter error

Tags: pentaho

When I publish the prpt file in Pentaho User Console(PUC), I am getting error in parameter field when I select parameter values. after select the value from drop down the value is disappear.
 (I have attached image) 
[image: Check the red color box error].
I have selected those values in prpt(Check the image)[image: Selected values in PRD]
 but its working fine in Pentaho Report designer(PRD). What is the solution?

Comment: Did you clear the cache in Pentaho?

Comment: @MarlonAbeykoon ya I cleaned all the caches.

Comment: Someone put down vote for this question may i know the reason?

Comment: @Pirinthan : Try unchecking the "**Validate Values**" !!

Comment: @Rishu Thanks it's working now. put as a answer then i can up vote and make as correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try unchecking the "**validate values**". It will work :)